# HTC Sense - What Is "Current Weather"?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, htc-sense, htc-desire-s, weather

I think this app is a part of HTC Sense. When i check weather, i get usual report:

[image]

But if i swipe down, i get "current" report:

[image]

From pictures you can see that reports differ by 2 degrees Celcius, however i once had not only difference in degrees but in day and night i.e usual report showed day while "current" report showed night (or vice versa..? can't recall).

Why there is a difference between both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Haifa (Current)' display is the weather at the position your phone thinks it is currently located at. In other words, the 'Current' refers to current position. The other 'Haifa' display is the weather at the extra city location that you have set up. The displays show different weather because the specific locations used by your phone within Haifa are presumably different, even though they are both within Haifa.

Comment: Mike, i have not set up any other extra city location. How to find out which extra city it shows weather for and how to change it to another extra city?

Comment: Boris_yo, You can add, rearrange or delete the extra cities by using the options: Menu >> Add, Menu >> Rearrange or Menu >> Delete. Those options only work on the extra cities, not the current location, so the rearrange would only have meaning if you set up more than one extra city.